# popToRootViewController is crashing when more than two view controllers are being popped

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

I have a strange situation with calling popToRootViewController on my navigation controller. If there are only one or two view controllers on top of the root to pop, it works just fine. If there are more than two view controllers on top of the root on the stack, it crashes. I've looked around all of the popToRootViewController complaints on this site and others and have tried setting animated to NO. This does not help. I've also seen some people citing an issue with iOS 3.0 with popToRootViewController on very old posts, but I am developing on iOS 4.0.

To be more explicit, if my stack looks like this: RootVC --> VC1 --> VC2. And then I do

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

from VC2, it pops to the root as expected. However, if my stack looks like this: RootVC --> VC1 --> VC2 --> VC3 and then do the same exact thing from VC3, it crashes. Any clues as to what could be the problem? I apologize if this is a really dumb question. I'm a newcomer to iPhone developement.

I am using the following code for pushing each of my views onto the stack:

```
-(void)pushViewNamed:(NSString *)viewname 
{
    iOvulate_3AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    NSString *viewControllerName=viewname;
    UIViewController *targetViewController=[[NSClassFromString(viewControllerName) alloc] initWithNibName:viewControllerName bundle:nil];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:targetViewController animated:YES];

    if ( [appDelegate.pdbool intValue] == 0 )
    {
        [viewControllerName release];
        [targetViewController release];
    }
}
```

I put the conditional release there because it solved a different problem I was having where IBActions on any view beyond the third view on the stack weren't working--as in touching inside a button was causing a message to be sent to a nil object that was supposed to be the view controller (or something like that?) and causing **EXC_BAD_ACCESS** error. Could this "fix" be causing the memory management problems you speak of?

Comment: Could be multiple reasons, but it's probably a memory management error. Could you post some code and show us what the error message says?

Comment: I don't know if your fix is the root of this problem, but it definitely isn't managing memory properly.  You should always be releasing targetViewController because you created it with an alloc, added it to the navigationController, and are done with it at that point. You should *not* be releasing viewControllerName in this method because you allocated it somewhere else and may still be using it.

Comment: @DrewC: Releasing targetViewController after adding to the navigation controller causes the reemergence of my old problem which is that IBActions in any view beyond the third view in the stack do not work when I have released targetViewController. I currently have a nil delegate. Could this be the problem?

Comment: Is there somewhere else in your code where you release view controllers added to the nav controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try looking at each of the View Controllers on your nav stack? Use:

```
[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:index];
```

To see the view controller at the corresponding `index`. If they appear all fine, then it must be something else in your code that is causing the crash. Hope that helps!

Comment: This was very helpful! It seems that after I push the fourth view onto the stack, it throws everything away--as in self.navigationController.viewControllers called from my third view on the stack returns an array containing three view controllers as expected, but calling it from my fourth view returns an array of zero view controllers. I guess I'm using too much memory?

Comment: Maybe you are using too much memory. Use the tools to to see what's happening in the background. There are plenty of tutorials online which will show you how to make use of them. Also, don't forget to accept the answer so people can use this later if they have a similar problem.